# Which activity is used to move files with in Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I was moving data from csv file available in Blob storage to Azure SQL DB using Data Factory. Once the  process is complete I need to move the processed csv file to some other location with in Blob storage.

What kind of activity and type i need to use to perform this task.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Data Factory supports built-in activities such as Copy Activity
>   and HDInsight Activity to be used in pipelines to move and process
>   data. You can also create a custom .NET activity with your own
>   transformation/processing logic and use the activity in a pipeline.
>   You can configure the activity to run using either an Azure HDInsight
>   cluster or an Azure Batch service.

Here's [a link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-use-custom-activities/)

Answer (score 0):

To do the second copy you can use the Copy activity in ADF. However if you want to do a 'move' then currently custom activity is the way to go.